# How to prevent Google from showing URLs in the description section of search results for my site

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, google-search, site-search

I have music website.  There are 46 album pages and each page has different player and files.

I just entered the one of album's URLs in a search engine. I found that Google is displaying player code in search result content.

For example, enter this URL in Google and check the results. Each result displays a .mp3 file in content section.  I see this:

> This page contains a demo of and documentation for the new jPlayer Playlist add-on, ... mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3", ...

I don't want Google to show the player code and mp3 files in search result.

- How can I hide audio files and player code from search engine?
- What would be the best solution for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It shows the URL in the meta description because that is what you entered as your search query in Google. Google will change the meta description and the title in their listings if they find something on the page more relevant to the search query that your pre-defined meta/title.

Why will anyone else be searching the exact URL's of your mp3's in Google? They won't be, so they won't see that in the meta description so it subsequently isn't a problem.

If you have an instance/example where the URL to your mp3's are being displayed in the snippet Google shows for a search query that people will actually use then we may be able to advise/help further.

Comment: i am selling .mp3 files as well so if google will crawl it and display it in search result then that will be problem for me. also it is displaying player code.  even if  i enter my site url that player code is appearing in content.  while i have entered nice meta description for that page already. can you suggest me best solution. what should i do?

Comment: Is jplayer.org your domain that you're referring to? If so, please provide an exact search query you are searching in Google and what URL shows in the listings with the direct URL's to your mp3 files.

Comment: no. i am not referring to jplayer. i am just entering my domain name in google. for example:   http://google.com   that is listing all the link there i found one of my album page there showing player code  and mp3 files in search result content. i don't want google to index my mp3 files in google. only mp3 files . i want google to index album content and everything else. could you please help me?

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm asking for. I want to know your exact domain, your exact search query and the exact URL for your domain you're looking at in Google. I've already answered why the URL's appear in the snippets shown if you are entering a URL into Google's search box.

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason behind this. Suppose you are searching any URL in Google and your page contains that URL.  Google will change your meta description. Due to this your search result's snippet is also changed. It Happens with by blog also. Don't worry, it is normal.

The main thing is, why would anyone search for a URL in Google?  For example my blog, `trickwarehouse.blogspot.com`: To find all indexed pages in Google, you have to type `site:http://trickwarehouse.blogspot.com` in Google search.  Then Google will display all indexed pages of my site.  If you type `site:http://trickwarehouse.blogspot.com alexa` in google search box and you will find that the snippet is changed in all results and now its displaying "alexa" in every post's snippet of my blog.

That was the reason. It's normal for all sites. Don't worry.